# Rider .Net Can't build my project sometimes

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, rider

Sometimes rider can't build my project with message: "another build is already in progress". Restarting doesn't help. Invalidate cache and restart helps, but it is too slow.
What's wrong?

- Rider 2021.2.2
- Language C#
- MsBuild 5.0.104

UDP
Looks like this

[image]

UDP rider [log file](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/qEub/ohXD1Bxgp)

Comment: Without more detailed diagnostics information, and even then, this question is probably better suited to be asked at JetBrains support (or search their [bugtracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RIDER) for potential reasons/solutions)

Comment: Is this error comes from IDE or MsBuild? How it looks like?

Comment: Christian.K, whre i can get this infirmation?
xtmq, added example pictures.

Comment: i updated .net sdk to 5.0.402, maybe this will help